# Issue with storing string with a backslash(\) in session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Here is a quick example:

```
function step1() {
    $data = array(
        'level_1' => array(
            'level_2' => 'abc\def'
        ),
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata("data", $data);
}
function step2() {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

As end result, data is not stored in session.

Comment: any error/exception ?

Comment: is other data stored properly? maybe the issue is in the implementation of `$this->session`?

Comment: is session library enabled?

Comment: It will work if written this way:
`function step1() {
    $data = array(
        'level_1' => 'abc\def'
        ),
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata("data", $data);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can separate with '\' using '.'...Think this may work

```
function step1() {
    $data = array(
        'level_1' => array(
            'level_2' => 'abc'.'\'.'def'
        ),
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
function step2() {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

Comment: are you sure,you are storing an array in another array?

Comment: `.'\'.` this will be syntax error coz u need one additional backslash

Comment: this should be `.'\\'.`

Comment: try using double quotes.. `'abc'."\".'def'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118802/discussion-between-hanan-ashraf-and-george-garchagudashvili).